# Programming languages that compile to native code and have the batteries included

Tags: programming-languages, code-generation, native

What are the programming languages that compile to native code and which have provided a comprehensive library with them?

Libraries that includes functionality such as Networking, File IO, RegEx, Database, Graphics, Multimedia, Win32 API bindings, File compression, etc.

Comment: I assume we are talking about particular compilers/vendor implementations?  Because I don't think any language satisfies what you are talking about.

Answer (score 14):

- I'll assume everyone has thought of C and C++.
- [Haskell](http://haskell.org) is the obvious one here.  In particular, if you want batteries included, you want the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/).
- [OCaml](http://caml.inria.fr/) fits this category, as well.
- [Go](http://golang.org/) is a new player that has (most of) the feature you asked.
- [The D programming language](http://digitalmars.com/d/) with it's standard library [Phobos](http://digitalmars.com/d/1.0/phobos/phobos.html).
- Some [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) dialects include a native compiler, like [Common Lisp](http://lisp-lang.org/) with its SBCL, CCL or ECL (to C) compilers.
- [Rust](http://rust-lang.org/) is a system programming language but doesn't include batteries but has [crates](http://crates.io/) ― to avoid stale standard library modules

Comment: See also: OCaml Batteries Included project: http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/

Comment: Speaking as a Common Lisp fan, while most serious implementations do compile to native code, the libraries were somewhat lacking last I saw.

Comment: C++ fits the _batteries included_ bill marginally, while C doesn't. It's neither good, nor bad, just an observation. Of course, they don't provide a heavy standard library like the OP asks, but you get to use the platform's API, but then one might not always get a portable solution.

Answer (score 8):

[Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) meets all those requirements.  This is a development environment based on the Object Pascal language.

Answer (score 2):

Is **Objective-C** with **Cocoa/CocoaTouch** an acceptable answer?

You can use this pair for programming applications running on devices with restrictive constraints on batteries (laptops and mobile phones).

Answer (score 2):

[Swift](https://swift.org/) by Apple, but now Open Source, compiles to native code and is available for OS X and Linux.

Batteries are completely included for Mac OS X and iOS through Apple's extensive libraries/APIs, and support for OS independence is on the way with the development of [core libraries](https://swift.org/core-libraries/).

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. The funny thing is, most OSes have native APIs for all that stuff. So all you really need is a language that can link in OS calls. Pretty much any compiled language worth its salt will do that.

Comment: But native OS calls are usually a **huge** PITA to use and are platform specific.  For about 99% of cases you want to abstract these away.

Comment: For most UI work, I've found I'm much happier using the native OS GUI support. Portable frameworks never look quite right, and they always manage to abstract away something I want.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working with Qt.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/index.html

Edit: a Nitpick..

A programming 'language' is a grammar and set of semantics and syntax. It contains NONE of the things you are asking about. What you want to know about is API's, not languages.

Comment: Qt isn't a programming language (yet).