# In what languages besides C can I write a C library?

Tags: c, dll

I want to write a library that is dynamically loadable and callable from C code, but I really don't want to write it in C - the code is security critical, so I want a language that makes it easier to have confidence that my code is correct.  What are my options?

To be more specific, I want C programmers to be able to `#include` this, and `-l` that, and start using my library just as if I had written it in C.  I'd like programmers in other languages to be able to use their favourite tools for linking to C libraries to link to it.  Ideally I'd like that to be possible on every platform that supports C, but I'll settle for Linux, Windows and MacOS.

Comment: This is rather less true of security than of other concerns.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is finally a decent answer to this question: [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org).

Answer (score 6):

Anything that compiles to native code. So you might Google for that - "languages that compile to native code."  See, e.g., [Programming languages that compile to native code and have the batteries included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797328/programming-languages-that-compile-to-native-code-and-have-the-batteries-include)

C++ is often the choice for this.  Compiles to native code and provided you keep your interfaces simple, easy to write an adapter layer.

Objective C and Fortran are also possible.

Comment: Actually he could use many more languages if he really wants to, for example using Python's C API as a wrapper (and including the necessary libraries inside his own), he could use Python.

Comment: I don't think that C++ is a good choice for a C library. Not at all.

Comment: @VladLazarenko care to justify?

Comment: Not just anything that compiles to native code. The current Go compiler from Google cannot, AFAIK, generate position-independent code.

Comment: @djechlin: Wrapping C++ code into C interface defeats the whole point of C++. Also, catching exceptions in C is not something you'd want to do (though possible on some systems), and making sure C++'s C-like interface never throws is extra trouble nobody needs.

Comment: @VladLazarenko it doesn't defeat the whole point of C++, but anyway.  Adapter layer is a `try/catch(exc) { return 1; }` layer.   Very simple.

Comment: @djechlin: Yeah, tell me about it. I want to see you having fun wrapping a few hundred classes and their relations into a nice C API, and then doing try-catch (BTW, there are "foreign" exceptions that you are not allowed to suppress in C++ code). Dealing with pointers to members that don't fit into `void*` because of a super cool "this" pointer adjustments... Been there, done that. But of course when the question boils down to just «Can I?» then hey, of course you can.

Comment: @VladLazarenko yeah, I've been there too.  It worked straightforwardly in my case.

Comment: And don't forget, you can do it with assembly too :)

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. Haskell compiles to native code, for example, but I'm not sure it's possible to provide a normal-looking C library in Haskell.  If I'm mistaken, pointers on how to do so would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: @PaulCrowley Haskell does have a C API, but it takes some extra work to make it look like you're interfacing with a normal C library.

Comment: @larsmans can you expand on this?  It sounds like you can answer this question better than I can.

Comment: @djechlin: on Unix/Linux (apparently not on Windows, but don't take my word for it), shared libraries must contain [position-independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code), i.e. code that executes regardless of where in a program's address space the library winds up after dynamic linking. C, C++ and (I think) Fortran compilers generally produce PIC, but the Google Go compiler doesn't yet. I'm not sure about Haskell compilers, I've never seen a shared library written in that language, even though native compilation is pretty much standard there too.

Comment: So to be clear, this answer is wrong and doesn't address what I asked, please don't upvote it.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are looking for a language with [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) compatibility or which can be described as resulting in [native](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_mode) code. So long as it can be compiled to a valid object file (typically an .obj or .o file) which is accepted by the linker, that should be the main criteria. You also then want to write a header file as a convenience for any client code which is written in C (or a closely related language/variant thereof).

As mentioned by others, you need a pretty good reason for choosing a language other than C as it is the lingua-franco of low-level/systems software. Assembler is an option, although harder to port between platforms. [D](http://dlang.org/overview.html) is a more portable - but less widespread - alternative which is designed to produce secure, efficient native code with a minimum of fuss. There are many others.

Answer (score 2):

Almost every security critical application I know of is written in C. I don't believe that there are any other language that has higher real status in producing secure applications.

C is being said to be a poor language for security by people who don't understand.

If you want C programmers to use your library, use C. Doing anything else is tying one hand behind your back whilst trying to walk on a balance beam (the gymnastics equipment). Sure, there are dozens of other languages that are CAPABLE of interfacing to C, but it typically involves using a C layer and then stuffing the C data types into a language specific data type (Java Objects, Python Objects, etc, etc), and when the call is finished, you use the same conversion back to a C data type. Just makes it harder to work with, and potentially slower if you don't get all the design decisions right. And people won't understand the source code, so won't like to use it (see more about this below).

If you want security, then write very good code, wearing your "security aspects" hat firmly on at all times, find a security mailing list or website and post it there for review, take the review comments on board, understand the comments, and fix any comments that are meaningful to fix. Distribute the source code to the users, so people can see what your code does. Those that understand security will know what to look for and understand that you have done a good job (or a bad job, whichever is applicable) - and those who don't will hopefully trust the right pople. If it's good, people will use it. If it's "hidden", and not easy to access, you won't get many customers, no matter what language you use.

Don't worry, you won't reveal anything more from releasing source. If there is a flaw in the code, and it is popular (or important) enough, someone will find the flaw, even if you publish only binaries. For those skilled in reverse engineering, not having source code is only a small obstacle.

Security doesn't stem from using a specific language or a specific tool, it stems from good design and good basic understanding of the problems with security.

And remember security by obscurity (whether that means "hidden source code" or "unusual language" or something else obscure) is false security.

Comment: Lots of security-centric open source projects have been shown to have the kinds of vulnerabilities that arise from using a non-pointer-safe language like C. Why should I believe that I'm a better programmer than all of them?  If I can get the computer to do the work of ensuring that I haven't made those particular mistakes, it is more likely to do a thorough job.

Comment: Since you are aware of the problems with using pointers, it should be relatively easy to know what areas to concentrate on. And languages then don't use pointers are typically written in C, which means that you end up with the same problem, but it's now hidden from your view [unless of course there is a "guaranteed safe language" - but so far I've not encountered a language that is guaranteed to be safe]. And of course, the point of codereview is that you get other people, who are experienced in finding flaws in code to look over the code - they will look for vulnerable use of pointers.

Comment: C is also said to be a poor language for security by people who *do* understand. Consider for example the work of Mark Miller on the language E, the work of Jonathan Rees on W7, and recent work by Anil Madhavapeddy et al on Melange. The 2007 paper "Melange: Towards a "functional" Internet" ([PDF](http://anil.recoil.org/papers/2007-eurosys-melange.pdf)) uses OCaml for a combination of efficiency and security. See their Table 1, which lists OpenSSH CERT vulnerabilities attributable to language weaknesses.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in ATS, http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/. ATS compiles via C, can be as efficient as C, and can be used in a way that is ABI-compatible with C. From the project website:

> ATS is a statically typed programming language that unifies implementation with formal specification. It is equipped with a highly expressive type system rooted in the framework Applied Type System, which gives the language its name. In particular, both dependent types and linear types are available in ATS. The current implementation of ATS (ATS/Anairiats) is written in ATS itself. It can be as efficient as C/C++ (see The Computer Language Benchmarks Game for concrete evidence) and supports a variety of programming paradigms

ATS's dependent and linear type system helps produce static guarantees about your code, including various aspects of resource management safety.

Chris Double has been writing a series of articles exploring the power of ATS's type system for systems programming here: http://bluishcoder.co.nz/tags/ats/. Of particular note is this article: http://bluishcoder.co.nz/2012/08/30/safer-handling-of-c-memory-in-ats.html

This document covers aspects of calling back and forth between ATS and C code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W6DYQApEqKgyBzMbvpCI87DBfLdNAQ3E60u1hUiMoU0

The main downside is that dependently-typed programming is still a daunting prospect, even for non-systems programming. The syntax of the language is also a bit weird: consider lexical quirks such as the use of `abst@ype` as a keyword. Finally, ATS is to some degree a research project, and I personally don't know whether it would be sensible to adopt for a commercial endeavour.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically,  it's going to be Fortran: less indirection (as in: my array is [here], not just a pointer to here, and this is true of most but not all of your data structures and variables).

However... There are many gotchas and quirks in Fortran: not, perhaps,  as many as in C but you probably know your way around C rather better than Fortran. Which is the point behind most of the comments saying 'Know your code' - but do you *really* know what your compiler is doing?

Knowing you, I'm prepared to take it on trust that you do,  for C. Most programers don't. You do not know and cannot know what a local JVM or JIT compiler does, and that's a black hole in your security model if you're using Java or C# r scripting languages.

Ignore anyone who tells you that the hairy-chested he-men of secure computing write their own assembler: they probably don't even know the security errors they're making in any and all nontrivial projects they release. Know your compiler,  indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it in [lua](http://www.lua.org/) - providing a C API to a Lua library is relatively straight forward. C++ is also an option, though of course you'd have to write C wrappers and make sure no exceptions can escape your functions. But honestly, if it's security critical the minor inconveniences of the C language shouldn't be that much of a big deal. What you really should be doing is prove the correctness of your program where feasible, and test extensively where it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a library in Java. JNI is normally used to call C from Java, but it can be used the other way around.